# WinForm DataBinding Hide Property in business object C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, attributes

My datagrid (DevExpress) automatically will populate a grid based on the public fields of a business object.

What attribute can I place on the field to tell WinForm databinders to ignore it?

```
[???HideFromDataBindingSources???]
 public bool IsSecurity
 {
     get { return _isSecurity; }
     set { _isSecurity = value; }
 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should decorate your property with [Browsable(false)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx)

Or even implement [ICustomTypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx) in your class and filter or dynamically add properties in more agile way.